# Listing all Outlook appointments for a given date using OLE and Delphi

Tags: delphi, outlook, ole

I've been trying to list the appointments for a given date (say today) on a tmemo by using OLE under delphi. It's been unsuccessful so far.
The basic code starts with

```
  try
    Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('outlook.application');
  except
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('outlook.application');
  end;

  Namespace := Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');
  Calendar := Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar);  // or use $000009
```

from there I tried to access Calendar.Items but I get different results each time and I don't see the recurring appointments even when I set the option to true.

Is there any way to list the appointments for a given date using Delphi 7?
Code is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer google'ing.

Here:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_22095294.html

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this a few years ago, and found it frustrating.  It was much easier to use a library that wrapped all the nuances of Outlook.  I strongly recommend [EasyMAPI](http://www.rapware.nl/prod_easymapi_page1.asp?SubMenu=EasyMAPI) from [RapWare](http://www.rapware.nl).

Edit:
Not tested, but I did find some [sample code](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_22095294.html) (if you scroll to the very bottom, you can see the text of the responses) that the author claims works.  This could serve as a starting point.

Comment: thanks but for what I need a full library is an overkill. Thank though for the info